# Trying to wire a new exhaust fan into existing vanity lights

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

I'm in the USA.  House was built in 1956.  Single pole switch upgraded from 15 amp to 20 amp.  The switch has both a white and black wire with no ground.

When I tried connecting the fan/light combo to the existing wires in the attic both the fan/light combo as well as the vanity light would either flicker or was dim even with the switch off.  These are led lights.  The exhaust fan company told me I couldn't wire them together because they thought my fan had Bluetooth.  When I corrected them and told them it was a standard fan THEN they said "Oh yeah our fans can't be wired into any other lights."  I find that to be a junk answer.  Homewerks brand fan.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What exactly are the existing wires in attic, to switch, and to existing vanity lights? What does each connect to? What is the model number of your fan/light combo? Pictures would help as well.

Comment: only the black wire will go to the switch

Comment: So the wires in the attic are only white and black.  I can trace them from the switch, up into the attic and then down into the vanity light.  Then it comes back up and runs back towards the panel (I'm assuming this is off the panel) and another runs from the vanity towards my bedroom.  Also @Ruskes all my switches that are single pole have the white and black at the switch so I'm guessing they have ran the power straight from the panel and then terminated at the switches.  I hope this is more helpful.  Thank you both for responding.

Comment: Is this a new fan, or are you replacing an existing fan?

Comment: It sounds like you have a switch loop (with only a black/white pair at the switch). Very common for houses built in the 50s. Please [edit] your question to provide a pic of the wiring at the switch and the wiring at the ceiling box where you're trying to install this light/fan.

Comment: Still only letting me post a single pic for some reason.  I am updating the post to show a drawing of what I ASSUME is accurate based on wires I can see from the switch box, to the vanity light and then towards the panel.  Where would you think I should make the connection for the new exhaust fan?

Comment: If the lights are dim and flickering even with the switch off a reasonable guess is that you wired the lights and fan in series without the switch in the circuit.  Your diagram needs to show clearly the junction boxes and cables.  You show the new fan not connected to anything by a cable, you show everything connected at the vanity light (which is possible) and you describe connections "in the attic" but don't show any attic junction box in your diagram.   If you draw all the junction boxes and cables we can help you connect them correctly.

Comment: I left the exhaust fan out of the diagram because it's currently disconnected.  Trying to figure out where I need to make the new connections is the current issue.  Also all of the wiring took place behind the vanity light.  There were zero boxes in my attic until I tried connecting into this circuit.  I now have a single junction box near the wires shown by the vanity when I reconnected everything as it was before I tried putting in the new fan/light.  I'm wondering if I need to run the new wires for the fan/light closer to the switch side or down into the vanity light itself like the others.

Comment: Got it.  You good with one switch controlling the fan and light together?  IE they are both on or both off?

Comment: If you can't post multiple images, upload them to imgur.com (SE's image hosting partner) and post the link to the group here. Someone will embed them for you.

Comment: Yes.  One switch is fine.  I'm going to take another look at this in a bit.  Thank you!  

Comment: @MikeBrown can you post photos of the inside of the vanity light box?

Comment: UPDATE!  I finally finished this project today.  I cleaned the old wiring up also.  Thank you all who helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *all* the wiring is in the box behind the vanity light, you probably have a switch loop so the easiest thing would be to have that switch control both the fan and light.

You'll have to run a cable in the attic, from the fan, down the wall to the vanity light.   You may need to replace the vanity light junction box with a larger one to accommodate more wiring.

If the switch will control the fan and light, you use three wires nuts as follows:

- Power: Black wires from the panel and bedroom, and the white wire from the switch (mark it with black tape).
- Neutral: All the white wires except from the switch
- Switched power: black wires from the switch, fan and light

You also need to handle ground correctly.  I won't cover that in detail here, but basically all the ground wires should be nutted together and if the box is metal, the one from the panel should be screwed to the box FIRST.

If you want to install a second switch to control the fan you'll need more cabling and the wiring will be different.

Comment: I was writing my own answer, but yours is good enough, discarded mine. **Except**: In a proper switch loop, white is actually *hot* and black is *switched hot* - the reverse of what you listed. But it isn't always that way, either is possible, and the way to tell is to use an NCVT on the switch to see which wire has power when the switch is turned off.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected my answer per your comment.  Unintuitive!  But seems to be the standard.

Comment: The standard, I believe according to @Harper , is that white is hot because that way if you use an NCVT and the circuit is live you will get a signal from the white, telling you right away that it is "hot". If you use white as switched hot then you might think it is a neutral, and since it wouldn't have power except when the switch is "on", you could get fooled in a dangerous way.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you so much.  I'm going to take another look at this in a bit.  I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Let me ask you this...  The manual from the fan says I can bundle both white wires together and both black wires together (one set for fan and one for the light).  Could I then connect these to new wiring and just connect black to black and white to white in the vanity box?

Comment: Do you mean the fan also contains a light?   If that is the case, and you *still* only have one wall switch to control all three (the vanity light, the fan, and its light) you would wire it as I described here, and inside the fan you would wire all the black wires to one another and all the whites to one another.  Probably.  Take this as general guidance.  The correct thing to do is read the manual.   I humbly suggest that if you can't follow the manual and adapt it to your circumstances, you should get an electrician to do the work.

Comment: That's what I am saying... the manual says to put white wires from fan and light together and then black wires from fan and light together and then connect them to power.  Just making sure that sounded right with people who may be more familiar with it since the company gave such poor advice when I called them and they also lied about their own product.  Haha.  Thanks so much.